# Django: Accessing ManytoMany field

Tags: django

I am currently facing the following challenge. As the visitor of my page you can select between different events. Let's say you clicked on one and now you are on the event page with the `id 1`. You can select between different tickets. Let's assume you selected Ticket 1 ( USD 100 ) with 19% VAT and Ticket 2 (USD 200) (includes Food) with 19 % + 7% VAT. Now you click on check out and the next page will list the following:

1x Ticket 1 - Total: USD 100

1x Ticket 2 - Total: USD 200

Total: USD 300

---

VAT 1 (19 %): USD 57 (19 + 38)

VAT 2 ( 7%): USD 14

---

Subtotal: USD 229

I am now struggling with this ManytoMany field. How would you access the individual tickets get the VAT from the respective ManytoMany field and then display them at the end of my template? I considered tuple, dictionary etc. but I am really struggling to find the best approach here. Did you ever face a similar code challenge?

```
class TicketTax(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        Event,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='ticket_taxes'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    percentage = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=4
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Ticket(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        Event,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='tickets'
    )
    ticket_tax = models.ManyToManyField(TicketTax, blank=True)
    price_gross = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=25,
        decimal_places=2
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_at = models.DateTimeField()
    end_at = models.DateTimeField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        choices=TicketStatus.CHOICES
    )
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Update 1:**

```
reserved_item = ReservedItem.objects.filter(order_reference=session_order_reference)
tax_dict = {}
        for i in reserved_item:
            ticket_subtotal = i.ticket.price_gross * i.quantity

            taxes_for_this_ticket = i.ticket.ticket_tax.all()
            for taxes in taxes_for_this_ticket:
                amount_of_taxes = ticket_subtotal * taxes.percentage
                tax_dict[taxes] = amount_of_taxes
```

Update 2 (solution):

**views.py**

```
d = {}
    for i in reserved_item:
        ticket_subtotal = i.ticket.price_gross * i.quantity

        taxes_for_this_ticket = i.ticket.ticket_tax.all()

        for taxes in taxes_for_this_ticket:
            amount_of_taxes = ticket_subtotal * taxes.percentage

            if taxes in d:
                d[taxes] += amount_of_taxes
            else:
                d[taxes] = amount_of_taxes

    for key, value in d.items():
        print(key.name, " Value: ", value)
```

template - checkout.html:

```
{% for key, values in taxes.items %}
    <p>
        {{key.name}}<br>
        {{values}}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Comment: Not clearl what u want exactly. Do u have a `TicketTax` and want to find all `Tickets` where it is applied to?

Comment: I have TicketTax and tickets which can have one ticket tax, many ticket tax or no ticket tax. I want to display all the ticket tax which is assigned to a ticket. Some ticket tax might have more then 1 ticket where it's assigned. Hope that makes is more clear

Comment: Did u try `taxes = Ticket.objects.ticket_tax.all()`?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming ticket is a Ticket object, 
`taxes_for_this_ticket =  ticket.ticket_tax.all()`

should work for you

Comment: That's the first part and works perfect. Now I am receiving different query_sets by looping through the tickets. E.g. Ticket 1 `<QuerySet [<TicketTax: TicketTax object (105)>, <TicketTax: TicketTax object (106)>]>`, Ticket 2`<QuerySet [<TicketTax: TicketTax object (105)>]>`

My goal is now to display TicketTax object (105) and TicketTax object (106) under total (see above) and give back the accumulated amount. That's where I am still struggling

Comment: not sure if I understand your question, but you can access individual ticket_taxes but iterating over ticket.ticket_tax.all(), e.g. `for tax in ticket.ticket_tax.all(): print tax.percentage`

Comment: Kind of, that's the right direction. My problem is, that e.g. Ticket 1 and Ticket 2 have the same tax. So I have to sum them up under total. And currently my dict, is just 'overwritten' by my for loop (see update 1).

Comment: Each ticket will have an `id` or `pk`, you can access the individual `ticket_tax` by filtering by `id` or `pk`.  In your view: `Ticket.objects.ticket_tax.get(pk=pk)`

Comment: After considering your feedback and some own research about dictionaries I now found a solution. See Update 2. Thanks a lot for your help!